# How to remove or disable plugin in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I need to disable Flash Player.
I tried to do this through the RequestContextHandler, but it did not work:

```
public class RequestContextHandler : IRequestContextHandler
{
    public ICookieManager GetCookieManager()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool OnBeforePluginLoad(string mimeType, string url, bool isMainFrame, string topOriginUrl, WebPluginInfo pluginInfo, ref PluginPolicy pluginPolicy)
    {
        bool blockPluginLoad = pluginInfo.Name.ToLower().Contains("flash");
        return blockPluginLoad;
    }
}
```

Whoer.net shows that Flash is not disabled.

[image]
[image]

How I can disable "pepflashplayer" plugin?

Comment: The documentation for `OnBeforePluginLoad` says _"Return false to use the recommended policy. **Modify and return true to change the policy**."_ - You're not changing the policy. [Link](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestContextHandler_OnBeforePluginLoad.htm)

Comment: @stuartd, Really ... Thank you! Will you do this as an answer?

Comment: Probably better if you write the answer showing how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аlso need to configure the plugin policy:

```
public class RequestContextHandler : IRequestContextHandler
{
    public ICookieManager GetCookieManager()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool OnBeforePluginLoad(string mimeType, string url, bool isMainFrame, string topOriginUrl, WebPluginInfo pluginInfo, ref PluginPolicy pluginPolicy)
    {

        bool blockPluginLoad = pluginInfo.Name.ToLower().Contains("flash");
        if (blockPluginLoad)
        {
            pluginPolicy = PluginPolicy.Disable;
        }
        return blockPluginLoad;
    }
}
```

Thanks to @stuartd

Comment: for version 79.1.360 this does not work, does anyone have a solution?